# Merge referrals from same domain in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, filter, localization, google-analytics, report

I don't know, but every time I think I finally figured out regular expressions, they somehow feel the need to prove me wrong.

I tried to merge all the referrals from `*.webcams.travel` together (ignoring/merging the different subdomains). But, as you can see in the Source report, it doesn't work. 
Instead, every subdomain referral gets listed: `de.webcams.travel`, `at.webcams.travel`, etc

**What do I need to change for it to work?**

[image: Create filter for custom Google Analytics report]

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the Google Analytics interface, but assuming that the Search/Replace strings actually allow RegExp, then your code looks correct. Alternately you might want to swap the `*` which means "match zero or more" with `+` which means "match one or more". You could also try the following: `([a-z]+\.)?webcams\.travel` which makes the initial alpha characters and dot optional.

Comment: You could also just use webcams.travel$ to match anything that ends with that string

Comment: @alexp Good idea, I can try that. I currently try `(.*)webcams\.travel` - unfortunately, I have to wait a full day in order to see if it works... - but my bigger question: shouldn't it work with the original RegExp anyway?

Comment: @SimonFerndriger looking at the documentation again, regexes aren't mentioned until the Advanced Filters section, which leads me to believe they don't work in Search and Replace filters.

Comment: @alexp Ah, this is interesting! Can you perhaps show me the part in the documentation where it is stated? Do you have any idea how I would have to set up the advanced filter in order to work in the desired way?

Comment: @alexp If this would be true, and regular expressions are only supported in advanced filters, why is there an example for search and replace with regular expressions? `Search String: example\.com/article/.*
Replace String: example\.com/article/`

Comment: @SimonFerndriger Never mind. I see now in the docs for search-and-replace where it says "The search expression is a regular expression." So I don't know why yours isn't working. Are you looking at data from the past by any chance? I'm pretty sure filters don't apply retroactively, so even if your filter is correct now, it won't clean up your old data.

Comment: @alexp OK, so far so good. Your question is very good, but no - I'm only looking at data after the day of making the regex changes. So it _should_ work. However, perhaps "Referral" is not the right element to change in the first place?

Comment: @SimonFerndriger That's a good point, it might not be. Campaign Source and Campaign path seem like likely candidates.